# json serialization c# windows phone and app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows

i'm new in writing apps for WindowsPhone and Windows 8.1.

I have the following problem: I can not serialize a json string via Datacontract in Windowsphone, but in Windows 8.1 it works without problems.

My Error Message: (SerializationException):

> There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[htwapp.SpeicherStrukturen.Lektures,
>   htwapp.WindowsPhone, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]. Input string was not in a correct format.

My Targetclass:

```
[DataContract]
    public class Lektures
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Semester { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PrDatum { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string VoDatum { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PrNr { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string EctsGrade { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Vermerk { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PrNote { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int EctsCredits { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PrTxt { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Versuch { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PrForm { get; set; }

 ... }
```

My method to serialize the string into the targetclass

```
private static List<Lektures> json2cource(String Jason)
        {
            List<Lektures> courcelist = new List<Lektures>() ;
            try {
                MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
                DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Lektures>));
                courcelist = (List<Lektures>)ser.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Jason)));
                return courcelist;
            }catch (SerializationException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return courcelist;
            }
        }
```

An now an example Json String:

```
[{
    "Status":"AB",
    "Semester":"20122",
    "PrDatum":"14.02.2013",
    "VoDatum":"",
    "PrNr":"1111",
    "EctsGrade":"",
    "Vermerk":"",
    "PrNote":"100",
    "EctsCredits":"5.0",
    "PrTxt":"TEXT",
    "Versuch":"1",
    "PrForm":"S"}, ...]
```

The methods to get the string are the same (post requests). The string in the windows version is identical with the string from windowsphone version.

If somebody would help me, i would be very happy :)

Greetings

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use other json serialization technologies like json.net

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 says to me the json.net functions wont work at windowsphone. And i want to create a solution for both platforms.

Comment: @kalenderdose, where does it say that? JSON.NET supports *all* .NET platforms. It's by far the most reliable JSON library for .NET.

Comment: Okay i found the mistake. I installed it over nuget, but it sems like he didn't installed it for my windowsphone project...

Answer (score 0):

i would still suggest json.net for doing this.
it works on all windows phone versions as well, i used it in my own project too.

you can simply serialize your own objects.